# Minimum of a list in a cell Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Struggling to visualise how I can do the following, as its a minimum of a calculated list in one cell formula. Lets say I have one data sheet, named `Sheet1`:

```
AAPL, TSCO, APPl 2D diff, APPL 3D diff, TSCO 2D diff, TSCO 3D diff,
10, 20, , ,,,
11, 19, , ,,,
11, 21, =(A4/A2)-1, , =(B4/B2)-1
12, 23, =(A5/A3)-1, =(A5/A2)-1, =(B5/B3)-1, =(B5/B2)-1,
13, 21, =(A6/A4)-1, =(A6/A3)-1, =(B6/B4)-1, =(B6/B3)-1,
```

So its easy to drag these formula down (its as a percentage). I have the time series for both and if I have 1 AAPL and 1 TSCO share its perfect. Then all I want is the minimum of the 2D Diff and min of 3D diff, easily obtained by `=MIN(C:C)` or `=MIN(D:D)`

But then lets say I want to vary the weights as so (`Sheet2`). So I have to go back to `sheet1` and then weight the 2d difference and 3d differemce, changing the weight each time, i.e. if we take the first weigh 5 + 100 for the 2D difference, I have to make a 7th column with the formula `=5*C4+100*D4`, then have to type `=MIN(G:G)` to find it, si there a way I can do this in one cell?

```
AAPL Weight, TSCO Weight, min 2D diff, min 3d diff
5,100,,
50,70,,
80,75,,
```

Then for each different weighting in this table, I currently go and do this manually. Is there a way I can cal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Sheet1` to `Sheet2`. I pre made the column with the said weighting formula, then just changed the weighting each cyel. The following code id what worked for me:

```
Sub Cycle_Through_Weights()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To 23:
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("E3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("W2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("X7:Y7").Select

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("C" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C" & i).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i
End Sub
```